# Recorrer objeto dentro de localStorage y obtener su valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Estoy intentando acceder a la posición 0 de la nota y del nombre del objeto estudiante dentro de localStorage, pero no puedo acceder de la manera en qué lo estoy haciendo. La idea es poder comparar todas las notas con el fin de obtener la nota mayor. Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Agradecido de antemano, saludos

```
 $("#registroEstudiantes").click(function(){

    var id = $("#id").val();
    var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    var nota = $("#nota").val();

    var estudiante = {
        id:id,
        nombre:nombre,
        nota:nota
    };

    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(estudiante));
    contador = localStorage.length + 1;
    listarEstudiantes();
    restablecer();
});


   $("#notaMayorEstudiantes").click(function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

        var clave = localStorage.key(i);
        var estudiante = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(clave));

        var nota_mayor = estudiante[0].nota;
        var nombre_estudiante = estudiante[0].nombre;

            if(nota_mayor < estudiante[i].nota){
                nota_mayor = estudiante[i].nota;
                nombre_estudiante = estudiante.nombre[i];
            }           

    }

     alert(nota_mayor + nombre_estudiante);   

});
```

Comment: ¿cómo es qué guardas los datos en localStorage?

Comment: @Christian, agregué la función al código para que quede un poco mas claro cómo guardo los datos en localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te hará la comparación correcta de valores `Number` to `Number` para definir la nota mayor.

```
$("#notaMayorEstudiantes").click(function() {
    var estudianteMayor = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(0)))

    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {              
      var clave = localStorage.key(i);
      var estudiante = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem(clave));

      if(Number(estudianteMayor.nota) < Number(estudiante.nota)) {     
        estudianteMayor = estudiante
      }
    }
    alert(estudianteMayor.nota + " " + estudianteMayor.nombre);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias primeramente definir las variables fuera del bucle si luego quieres invocarlas en el `alert`, por otra parte, en el bucle del `for` ya tienes el objeto y es unico por tanto no seria necesario el indicador de posicion `[0]`. En tu codigo quedaria así:

```
$("#notaMayorEstudiantes").click(function(){

  let nota_mayor=0;
  let nombre_estudiante = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

        let clave = localStorage.key(i);
        let estudiante = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(clave));

            if(nota_mayor < estudiante.nota){
                nota_mayor = estudiante.nota;
                nombre_estudiante = estudiante.nombre;
            }           
  }
  alert(nota_mayor+" "+nombre_estudiante);

});
```